# AS3 - If statement - Next Scene

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, if-statement, drag-and-drop

I am creating an interactive game and want the user to be able to drag and drop a coin in a box. Once the user has done this, they can then go to the next scene, but can only access next scene if they have dropped the coin in the right box.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a `MOUSE_DOWN` and a `MOUSE_UP` event listener in conjunction with `movieclip.startDrag()` and `movieclip.stopDrag()` to handle the dragging and dropping, then all you need to do is a `hitTestObject(..)` when the coin is dropped.

The code is pretty straight forward in structure:

```
coin.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown);
coin.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseUp);

function onMouseDown(e:Event):void
{
  // When mouse button is held down, begin dragging coin movieclip
  coin.startDrag();
}

function onMouseUp(e:Event):void
{
  // When mouse button is released, stop dragging
  // the coin and check if is is over the box
  coin.stopDrag();
  if(coin.hitTestObject(box))
  {
    // Go to next scene
  } 
}
```

Comment: thanks. the coin drags but once the coin has dropped how to get it to play a video which is on the next scene? - not too sure on the if statement. thanks

Comment: I keep getting this error: 


Scene 1, Layer 'AS', Frame 1, Line 4 Warning: 1090: Migration issue: The onMouseDown event handler is not triggered automatically by Flash Player at run time in ActionScript 3.0.  You must first register this handler for the event using addEventListener ( 'mouseDown', callback_handler).